# Can one see an angel?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, malach-angel

Are there any sources saying how one can see or call an angel?

Comment: Those that know don't tell, those that tell don't know.

Comment: Cute line @GershonGold

Comment: Yet the Gemara in Brachos 6a or 7a talks about seeing Demons what would be the difference seeing an angel?

Comment: I don't understand people who downvote without commenting.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't. As I answered in your previous question ([here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100149/where-is-heaven-located/100151#100151)) about the angel's nature, they are not (normally) material. As such they are invisible to the human eye, just as other immaterial things are.

To me, they are like math formulas, that can be perceived with our minds but not seen with the physical eyes under normal conditions (Hashgacha Klalit).

**Disclaimer**: none of the above denies or contradicts G-d's exclusive right for Hashgacha Pratit (a personal Miracle), either by materializing the angels (see Avraham's guests) or by letting person's senses to perceive the immaterial (see וכל העם רואים את הקולות at Matan Torah or Bilam seeing the angel when allowed to).

Answer (score -1):

According to [my understanding of] the Midrash ([B"R 53](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.53?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi)), seeing things is sanctioned by G-d:

> אָמַר רַבִּי בִּנְיָמִין הַכֹּל בְּחֶזְקַת סוּמִין עַד שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מֵאִיר אֶת עֵינֵיהֶם, מִן הָכָא וַיִּפְקַח אֱלֹהִים אֶת עֵינֶיהָ.
>
> (R' Binyamin said, everyone is [considered[ blind until G-d opens their eyes)

So why do we see trees? Because G-d allows us to (anatomy, biology, physics etc) and allows trees to be seen. Same for angels - it's up to G-d if we could see them.

This is explicitly mentioned in the Torah ([Num 22, 31](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.22.31?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וַיְגַל יְהוָה אֶת־עֵינֵי בִלְעָם וַיַּרְא אֶת־מַלְאַךְ יְהוָה נִצָּב בַּדֶּרֶךְ וְחַרְבּוֹ שְׁלֻפָה בְּיָדוֹ וַיִּקֹּד וַיִּשְׁתַּחוּ לְאַפָּיו׃
>
> Then the LORD uncovered Balaam’s eyes, and he saw the angel of the LORD standing in the way, his drawn sword in his hand; thereupon he bowed right down to the ground.

Comment: Technically this is correct but it's not complete. Consider adding the sources surrounding Hagar seeing the angels - there are definitely ways that one can bring himself to a level where he's worthy of seeing them.

Comment: @DonielF No, it depends solely on G-d's will.

Comment: Literally everything depends solely on G-d's will. Like I said, this is technically correct but incomplete: there are many sources which discuss at what point G-d is willing to grant one this ability.

Comment: So at what point? @DonielF

Comment: @Moshe Specifically? I'm not sure. Generally speaking? Bereishis Rabbah 45:7 contrasts Hagar, a *servant* of the Avos, who saw several angels without any fear, to Manoach, a full Jew many centuries later, who was scared he would die for having seen an angel.